# Exporting a list of images from Google Photos or DropBox as CSV

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-photos, google-photos-api

Do any of the major online photo storage/sharing platforms offer a reasonable way to export a set of image URLs and titles as something like a CSV or fetch them as JSON from a REST API?

I am trying to get any sort of clean list of title, url value pairs for all the images in a particular folder or gallery.

Google Drive/Photos would be my prefered platform, but I would switch to DropBox or other service if I could easily get such an export list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use Google Drive, you'll probably end up using these properties from [File Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations):

> webViewLink - a link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor

or

> webContentLink - a link for downloading the content of the file in a
>   browser.

You can fetch this properties using [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) or [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get).

Answer (score 0):

For Dropbox, you would use the /2/files/list_folder[/continue] endpoints to list the desired files:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder
- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue

Then, you can use /2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings to create shared links for the desired files:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings

Or, to retrieve existing shared links, use /2/sharing/list_shared_links:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links

Those are links to the documentation for the HTTPS endpoints themselves, but we recommend using one of the official SDKs if possible:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation

Those have corresponding native methods for the HTTPS endpoints.